# Difference between string.replace(c,'',1)) and string[1:]

Tags: python, recursion

So I am trying to trace a recursive function and I'm having difficulties tracing this:

I'm trying to trace a code on permutations but this confuses me:

```
# doesn't work
def permutations(string):
    if len(string) == 1:
        return string

    recursive_perms = []
    for c in string:
        for perm in permutations(string[1:]):
            recursive_perms.append(c+perm)

    return set(recursive_perms)

# works
def permutations(string):
    if len(string) == 1:
        return string

    recursive_perms = []
    for c in string:
        for perm in permutations(string.replace(c,'',1)):
            recursive_perms.append(c+perm)

    return set(recursive_perms)
```

I'm horrible at tracing recursion currently, and I don't know the difference between the first and second function but the 2nd one works first one doesn't. The difference is the replace. Whats the different between the replace and doing string[1:]? Is there anyway you could change the replace into string slicing?

Comment: What do you mean that the first function "doesn't work"?  What is it supposed to do, and what does it actually do?

Comment: Desired output for permutations('abc') is : {'abc', 'cba', 'bac', 'acb', 'bca', 'cab'}. The function that works does this, the function that does not work does: {'abc', 'acc', 'bcc', 'bbc', 'cbc', 'ccc'}

Comment: Note that `string[1:]` slices off the first character, but `c` is not always the first character...

Comment: why not just use `itertools.permutations`?

Comment: Practising recursion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`str.replace(old, new[, count])` replaces `old` with `new`, optionally only for the first `count` instances

`str[1:]` returns a slice of `str` from the character at the second index until the last index, effectively returning the entire string except for it's first character.

What really happens when you call `str[1:]` is that you're calling `str.__getitem__(slice(1, None))`